When `recover()` is called, what value is returned to the caller?
Strictly speaking, what value will be returned to the caller of f1() or f2()?
//`T` is some type.
func f1() T {
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            fmt.Println("recover")
        }
    }()
    g() //panics
    return something
}

//`T` is some type.
func f2() (v T) {
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            fmt.Println("recover")
        }
    }()
    v = X //assignment
    g() //panics
    return something
}

As far as I tested, f1() returns the zero value of T and f2() returns X.
Question
Is the behavior guaranteed by the spec or UB (undefined behavior)?
(The latter case can be rephrased as "is it allowed to implement a Go compiler which makes f1() return, for example, a uniform random value of type T?")
Handling panics says (emphasis mine):

The recover function allows a program to manage behavior of a panicking goroutine. Suppose a function G defers a function D that calls recover and a panic occurs in a function on the same goroutine in which G is executing. When the running of deferred functions reaches D, the return value of D's call to recover will be the value passed to the call of panic. If D returns normally, without starting a new panic, the panicking sequence stops. In that case, the state of functions called between G and the call to panic is discarded, and normal execution resumes. Any functions deferred by G before D are then run and G's execution terminates by returning to its caller.

It does NOT explain at all what value will specifically be returned to the caller of G.

There's nothing all that special about recover() here, aside from it not bubbling the panic up further. Consider it a bare return at the point where a panic happens. Inside the deferred func, you can modify the return values if they're named and it'll work like a normal defer would.

In the Return statements section of the spec it states:

Regardless of how they are declared, all the result values are initialized to the zero values for their type upon entry to the function. A "return" statement that specifies results sets the result parameters before any deferred functions are executed.

So, unless you alter them, via a return statement or amending named result parameters, a zero value will be returned.

Thank you. I've read the section, but I think we cannot be confirmed that the result values are also used in the context of recover(). As far as I tested (i.e. empirically), they are, but the spec seemed not to mention any relationship between the result values and recover(). Though the spec says G's execution terminates by returning to its caller, it is too strong assumption the word returning here refers to (implicitly executed) return statement; it is also possible the word is just used as a general English word whose meaning requires explicit definition I cannot find.

The quote in your question states that "normal execution resumes" (which would include handling the results). The last sentence is really just clarifying that deferred statements are run (which could really be inferred from "normal execution").
